# Is there a freely downloadable LEGO set and part dataset?

Tags: set-database

I'm working on a project that will require a list of all sets including all of the parts they contain. I'm aware of at least three sites which have this information ([Peeron](http://peeron.com), [BrickLink](http://bricklink.com), and [Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com)), but I haven't been able to find a way to download all of this data easily.

The closest thing I have been able to find so far is the [Brickset API](http://www.brickset.com/webservices/), but Brickset only has a limited amount of set metadata (year, theme, part count, etc) and does not seem to have a full listing of parts contained in each set.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wasn't able to find anything like this, so I contacted the admins of the sites that I mentioned in the question. Rebrickable was kind enough to send me a dump of their set inventories under a Creative Commons 3.0 BY-SA license, which basically means that you can do whatever you want with the data as long as Rebrickable is acknowledged as the source and you share any updates that you make.

I've created an archive which contains a spreadsheet for each set that was in the dump that I received. Hopefully this is useful to someone else.

[Lego Set Inventories as of March 2014](http://joncraton.org/files/lego_sets_20140302.7z)

Update:

The raw data that I used to create these spreadsheets is now available [directly from Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/downloads) and is updated monthly there. I also maintain [software to build an SQLite database from these dumps](https://github.com/jncraton/rebrickable-sqlite).

Comment: This is great! I've been looking for something like this to create a "cross match" application, basically an app that would take inventory of the sets that you currently own(and underlying pieces), and compare it against other sets you do not own to see if you can fulfill any other sets (or get close) and therefore not have to buy that set again. Just use the pieces you have. You wouldnt happen to have an updated version of this extract, would you? Some 2014 sets my son has arent in here. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my link and added a note about getting this data directly from Rebrickable. If you aren't familiar with Rebrickable, you should check it out. It sounds like it does exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This is a very suitable solution.