# How can I find out what parts are in a Lego set?

Tags: building, piece-information

I am building an inventory of all my LEGO pieces and I am looking for a website that can give the pieces in a set with only the set number. It would be easier if there was information for many LEGO sets with the full inventory. I also will need to have a file of all LEGO parts.

Comment: I have found a file that may help. [Here it is](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1908/2835). I haven't looked at it yet. I'll add it as an answer if it is right.

Comment: [Peeron](http://peeron.com) sounds just like what you're looking for. You can add sets to your account, and view how many of a certain piece you own, and in what colours.

Comment: Peeron USED to be awesome. Then, one day, I came home with some new sets and Peeron HAD NO CLUE. That was about three years ago, and the only sets I've added since then are the architecture sets, since they were seriously easy to remember. So, currently I'm adrift in the inventory department. *frump*

Answer (score 14):

Here are the options that I'm aware of along with some basic pros and cons:

### [Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/)

Rebrickable provides set inventories for nearly all sets. It includes sets from all time, and is still being updated as new sets come out. Rebrickable also provides all set inventories for offline use via its [download page](http://rebrickable.com/downloads).

### [Bricklink Inventory Reference](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogInv.asp)

Bricklink probably provides the most complete and up to date set inventory data. These inventories are also very detailed and include extra parts, sticker sheets, etc. If you are a seller on Bricklink, you can also part out sets into your inventory which could be useful to you at some point.

### Brickset / Lego.com

TLG provides nearly complete inventories for sets online via the [replacement parts page](https://service.lego.com/replacementparts). You can use this to get part information from your sets, but the interface is lacking because this isn't really what the page is meant for.

[Brickset](http://brickset.com) provides this same part data in a format which is much better for viewing. Simply search for a set and use the "Parts" tab to view contents if they are available.

These resources have a couple of downsides:

1. They only include relatively new sets.
2. Set inventories aren't as complete as Peeron or Bricklink.

### [Peeron](http://peeron.com)

This site is great for old sets, but it isn't updated anymore.

Comment: I use Rebrickable and have found the site-owner to be very friendly and open to feedback. As you point out, the philosophy is to help build sets, not to catalog each variation of a piece. For that reason, the site originally did not distinguish between some colors such as the "old" and "bley" tones of gray. I see the site now does distinguish between them, but unfortunately for me I had entered the bulk of my collection before that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [bricklink catolog](http://www.bricklink.com/catalog.asp). They also have inventories like Peeron, but
a little bit more detailed (like part variations)
and also include stuff like extra parts and Ninjago cards.