# Identification please

Tags: set-identification, city

I got hold of a lot of loose LEGO; included were three closed packages without assembly instructions. Two of these were numbered as 7 and 8 respectively, the third one is without numbering.

I attach pictures of the parts and would be very grateful, if someone could identify them so I can download instructions before my little grandson comes to visit in a few weeks :)

**Package "7"**

[image]

**Package "8"**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOfUm.jpg]

**Unknown Package**

[image]

Comment: Maria, Welcome to stack exchange. Since this is the same question as your previous question, can you add this picture to it and close this question? Your other question already has an answer :)

Comment: Maria, if this came in the same batch as your other posts, I assume it comes from the same set and you should close this question and add the picture to the already answered question. If it did not, this is a valid Q - just let us know.

Comment: This came in a different batch, Phil. - and thank you again for your previous id!!

Comment: On second thought - there are no green plates in 60004 Fire Station, so this package comes from another set. The problem is - these bricks are very common so difficult to determine which set they came from.

Comment: I cannot figure this one out - the 6x12 in bright green only comes in 16 sets (according to [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3028&in=S&colorID=36&ov=Y)) and none of those sets have 1x2 bricks with technic holes in them, in black. Did this all come from one sealed LEGO-labeled bag?

Comment: Oh and yes, this bag is from the same set - builds parts of the main garage.

Answer (score 3):

Given the size of the set (indicated by the fact that there are at least 8 bags), the occurrence of the [Item 2584c003 - winch with reel](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=2584c003#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) and the [Item 41539 - 8x8 light bluish gray plates](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=41539&idColor=86#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:86,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) in package "7", it looks like you have parts of set [60004 Fire Station](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=60004-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) in your hands, specifically one of the upper floors of the building, together with parts of the emergency pole.

[image]

Package "8" is also part of set 60004 Fire Station, specifically parts of one the two main garages next to the office tower part of the Fire Station, the roof of the garage and some of the sidewalk.

Answer (score 1):

One of the key pieces here is the Dark Blue [Part 3039 - Slope 45° 2 x 2](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3039), which is a fairly limited color.

Of the 5 sets using more than 8 of that element (your picture contains 10), there are none that contain at least 2 more of the other elements pictured.

As @PhilB commented, the 6x12 plate is also a rare piece. There are 0 sets that have both the Bright Green 6x12 plate *and* the Dark Blue slopes. The light bluish gray bricks are also not generally seen with those other two.

**This is an assortment of bricks from a number of sets.**

---

The small bag may be able to be identified to the set it belongs in, but the picture of bag is not clear enough. Some elements are partially hidden by others or glare, and the color isn't clear enough. If a picture of the bag is taken more zoomed-in and on a white background (like a piece of paper), we may be able to ID it.

I was able to find out this information by [downloading a list of sets and pieces](https://rebrickable.com/downloads) and turning it into a local relational database. I then queried that database to attempt to find sets which contained more than one of the different types of pieces pictured.

The other numbers, such as how many sets contain the piece/how rare a piece is can be done with a simple query, but many LEGO-related websites with parts listings have this information freely available.

Comment: Yeah almost no sets ever have that many light-bley 2x4s

Comment: Also the Technic [pin/axle connector](https://rebrickable.com/parts/32013) is in almost no sets in both red and yellow, and the sets they DO appear in look unlikely to have a polybag with just one of each in it.

Comment: Thank you, everyone - we'll add it to our 'general' Lego box and try be creative with it :)

Comment: Can you please link to where you found this information, since your answers seem so definite that you're using a database rather than memory. That helps us all learn how to answer these questions ourselves rather than just coming back here hundreds of times with new photos. Thanks.

Comment: @Mσᶎ I downloaded the files from https://rebrickable.com/downloads and converted them to a local database which I queried to find the information.

Comment: @CreationEdge I didn't realise those inventories were so readily available, thanks for that.

Comment: @Mσᶎ I didn't either, but found it through http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/is-there-a-freely-downloadable-set-and-part-dataset

Comment: And I use the "Catalog Item" search on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com) to do my sleuthing :)