# I need to know every LEGO's part number, name, and a picture of it

Tags: bricks-and-pieces

(spoilers) I saw The LEGO Movie and when Lucy looked at a Legeo piece she automatically knew it's part number, name, and other information about it. I thought this was really cool, and knew I could do this with a computer program, but how on Earth am I going to find every single LEGO's part number, and name? I have tried websites such as http://brickset.com, and http://bricklink.com, but they organize by category. What I need is a table of all of the LEGO pieces with their part number, and, name. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome. What is the problem with the database that BrickLink maintains? Even if they organize by category, since you are a programmer, flattening the categorized list is a few minutes work. Have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

There are several places you can go to to download a catalog of LEGO parts. All these catalogs use a different part number scheme than LEGO officially uses (due to the fact that until a few years ago, LEGO part information was a company secret). In no particular order:

- [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogDownload.asp). This is the most expansive catalog, and has a dedicated page for creating a customized download of its catalog (the link I just pasted).
- [LDraw.org](http://ldraw.org/parts/latest-parts.html). This focuses more on 3D descriptions of the bricks (which might be useful for your program too) but does contain a basic parts list (part number and name). Again, the link I provided takes you straight to a download page.
- [Rebrickable.com](https://rebrickable.com/downloads). They have several different parts lists, including [a list with all parts (direct csv download)](https://rebrickable.com/files/pieces.csv.gz).

Also note that [a similar question has been asked before](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/is-there-a-freely-downloadable-set-and-part-dataset), and you might get some more info from looking at that question.